# How to downgrade my flutter version when installed with Snap and not manually?

Tags: flutter

I have upgraded my version of flutter by mistake and I need to go back to the version 1.20.3 because the one I am using now is not stable.
I downloaded flutter using the first option (snap) and not manually, so I dont know how I can downgrade my version to 1.20.3.
Please, someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command

```
flutter downgrade 1.20.3
```

Edit:

The downgrade command is deprecated. Use the following method

Switch to the appropriate channel ( stable, master, beta )

```
flutter channel stable
```

cd into flutter directory and run the following command

```
git checkout v3.7.1
```

then run

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: Showing There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".

Answer (score 0):

When using snap, cd to the directory of flutter eg:/home/username/snap/flutter/common/flutter
Use the command flutter sdk-path to find this directory.
Then checkout to the required branch.
For that use git checkout 3.7.12,
Then run flutter doctor so it will build the system.